# how to change properties of Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

[image: gallery]

The attached image is a `Gallery` view. Like http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Here the images are started from center postion. But I want to start it from left side.

How can i do it? Is there any property to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out ,the gallery view always starts from center ,to align the images from the left we have to obviously adjust the left margin of the Gallery view .The code below could explain more.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


MarginLayoutParams mymlp = (MarginLayoutParams) ga.getLayoutParams();
   mymlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels/2 + 60), 
                mymlp.topMargin, 
                mymlp.rightMargin, 
                mymlp.bottomMargin
  );
```

ga  - > gallery view object

60 ->  this value can be adjust with respect to the width of the image in the gallery ,my imageview width in the gallery is 50